# Cannot find classmap.h

Tags: drivers, kernel, make

When i execute:

```
 make modules
```

i get the error:

```
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `relocs'.
CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
HOSTCC  scripts/selinux/genheaders/genheaders
scripts/selinux/genheaders/genheaders.c:13:22: fatal error: classmap.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/selinux/genheaders/genheaders] Error 1
make[2]: *** [scripts/selinux/genheaders] Error 2
make[1]: *** [scripts/selinux] Error 2
make: *** [scripts] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like perhaps you are missing the kernel source code?  Maybe try installing the appropriate [linux source package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-source) or [linux kernel headers](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-headers)?